# Is overflow of abs well defined?

Tags: c++

Is the behavior of the following code well defined?

```
int32_t i = -0x80000000;
uint32_t u = abs(i);
```

There may be an overflow/underflow on the first line. But on platforms when that is ok, does the second line have defined behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean `-0x80000000` with seven 0s? The behavior of `abs(-0x8000000)` is certainly well-defined (both `uint32_t` and `int32_t` contain `±0x8000000` in their valid range *if those types exist*.

---

When the standard says one behavior is undefined, it is undefined even if some particular platform work in some defined way.

The C++'s `abs` function is taken from C, and the C standard says (§7.20.6.1/2):

> The `abs`, `labs`, and `llabs` functions compute the absolute value of an integer `j`. **If the
>   result cannot be represented, the behavior is undefined.<sup>259)</sup>**
>
> <sup>259) The absolute value of the most negative number cannot be represented in two’s complement.</sup>

So the result of `abs` is undefined. Pratically it will return `0x80000000`, but that's not the behavior defined by the standard.

Comment: No, that would be "unspecified". Unspecified behavior is a case where the standard says "however your platform does it"; unsigned integer overflow is an example case. Undefined behavior is where the standard requires an implementation to have no specific behavior; the behavior may differ across application runs, across compilations, across machines, and have no systematic pattern.

Comment: Yes, I meant seven 0s. Thanks for the quote from standard.

Comment: @BillyONeal:  Actually I just want to say, that codes works on some platform ≠ it is defined behavior.

Comment: @Billy ONeal: That's not what undefined behavior or unspecified behavior mean. Undefined behavior means that the standard places _no requirements_ on the behaviour of an implementation. Unspecified behavior means that the implementation must conform to a range or set of allowed behaviours but doesn't have to document which behaviour it follows.

Comment: Undefined behavior is "behavior for which this International Standard imposes no requirements" Any response by the implementation is perfectly OK. There is nothing wrong with a two's complement implementation returning the most negative number as the absolute value of the most negative number. There's nothing wrong with making the application croak, either.